# how to fix issue with ansible win_hotfix module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing a ansible playbook for installing hotfix in windows 2016 using network share as source in win_hotfix module for ansible. I wrote below mentioned playbook for that.

I am running ansible in virtual environment for python 3.5.2 in cycle server having Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
(using putty to access cycle server) inside a VED hosted on windows 10 machine and VED is having windows 7 configured in it.I am able to access msu file manually through windows file explorer

'''

```
- name: install hotfix
  win_hotfix:
    hotfix_kb: KB4077525
    source: \\SERVER-IP\hotfix\win2016\some msu file
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: <username>
    ansible_become_pass: <password>
```

'''

I expect the output to be 
'''

```
TASK [install hotfix] 
**********************************************************
passed => {"changed": true,
```

'''
but the actual output is 
'''

```
TASK [install hotfix] 
**********************************************************
fatal: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "the path set for source 
\\\\SERVER-IP\\hotfix\\win2016\\some file.msu does not exist or is not a 
file", "reboot_required": false}
```

'''

Comment: I don't think so the SOURCE supports network path browsing. Can you run this after copying to some drive ? If it is working then you can map the drive and then use the above module after that

Comment: i am able to run it after copying to local disk. Even i tried mapping drives. but we are not able access mapped drive contents from ansible. we are getting error as ''' TASK [map network drive] 
changed:  => {"changed": true}

TASK [copy contents] ***********************************************************
fatal:: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\Windows\\", "msg": "Cannot copy src file: 'H:\\hotfix\\win2016\\windows10.0-kb4077525-x64_c12a49a72b532c0403d400c6d637265dc0a1a9cd.msu' as it does not exist", "src": "H:\\hotfix\\win2016\\<some msu file>

Comment: can you provide debug logs for this ? can you access the drive with the same creds that ansible is using ?